# iOS CORS headers

Tags: jquery, ios

I have a own Webserver (is self made application with works as a http server on port 8080). This webserver serves html requests which contains jQuery load requests to fill sections.

Those load requests fails on iOS devices.

I added the headers:

> Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Ranges:bytes
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*,origin, x-requested-with
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
>
> Cache-Control:no-cache
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip
>
> Content-Type:text/html
>
> Date:Mon, 6 Nov 2017  GMT
>
> ETag:"188bc74235f3a445098ca74fb716715c"
>
> Pragma:cache
>
> Server:Web Server v1.5

but anyway the load fails on IOS.

Is there more headers I must satisfy to make this work?

**EDIT:** I found out the Content-Encoding: gzip is the header that faults. If I disable the compression, it works. How can I keep the compression on iOS?

Comment: Did you try adding `Accept-Encoding: gzip`?

Comment: Isn't it the client who has to add accept-encoding to the request?

Comment: Yes. English is **mandatory** at Stack Overflow, even if we both speak Spanish.

Comment: thank you. the client requests it with the Accept-Encoding: gzip and I respond with Content-Encoding: gzip (and the compressed data). But, if the block is $().load() , it does not work on IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Content-Length:-1 I was posting on the headers is illegal somehow. Removing it , and activating GZIP again works fine on IOS.